How do I revert to default address in dnsmasq if the override addresses fail?
for example, if I have something like
address=/steamcontent.com/192.168.0.225

which redirects to my server (192.168.0.225), how do I make it go back to steamcontent.com if my server goes down?
Currently, if my server goes down, requests to steamcontent.com will timeout.

You can't. dnsmasq is a DNS server, it doesn't check whether the address you defined is up and what it is. It's simply not its job.
You need to have some additional service which checks the availability of your server, and reconfigures dnsmasq dynamically according to the outcome of the check.
